# Reasons why users are asked required to re-authenticate with Google integration

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm working on a product that has created an integration with Google Drive in which users have to authenticate their account in order to access their drive files.

As far as I understand, often there are reasons beyond the token expiring that requires the user to re-authenticate. We've gotten lots of negative feedback based on this interaction and I'm hoping to gather a list of reasons that re-authentication is sometimes required.

The two I'm familiar with are:
Change in device
Change in location

I would appreciate any advice on other reasons or implications for causing a user to re-authenticate with Google for integrations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A token might stop working for one of these reasons:
>
> - The user has revoked access.
> - The token has not been used for six months.
> - The user changed passwords and the token contains Gmail scopes.
> - The user account has exceeded a certain number of token requests.
>
> There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user account per client. If the limit is reached, creating a new token automatically invalidates the oldest token without warning. This limit does not apply to service accounts.

Check out the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) for more details on auth and token expiration.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the information I was looking for!